# Playblast query compression

Tags: python, maya, mel, pymel

I'm working on a custom playblast tool for Maya and I'm running into a little problem on how to query the available compressions for each format to perform the playblast.

I can use:

```
import pymel.core as pm

availableFormats = pm.playblast(query = True, format = True)
print availableFormats
```

The result I get is `['qt','avi','image']`. That is fine but now I need the compression options.

When I use

```
import pymel.core as pm

availableCompressions = pm.playblast(query = True, compression= True)
print availableCompressions
```

I get:

```
[u'Codec IYUV', u'MS-RLE', u'MS-CRAM', u'MS-YUV', u'Toshiba YUV411', u'TSCC', u'TSC2', u'none']
```

Which are the compressions options for the 'avi' format.

So, question:

How can I query the compressions for a specific format?

I tried passing:

```
pm.playblast(query = True, format = 'qt', compression  = True)
```

but it does not work, because, of course, query flag only permits booleans...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a python binding bug. 
Doing in Mel :

```
whatIs changePlayblastFormat;
// Result: Mel procedure found in: /path/mayaxxxx/scripts/others/performPlayblast.mel //
```

you can find that they query the encoding formats like this :

```
string $selectedFormat = `optionMenuGrp -q -value playblastFormatWidget`;
string $lEncodings[]   = `playblast -format $selectedFormat -q -compression`;
```

So my suggestion would be be to use a mel eval for this case :

```
pm.mel.eval('playblast -format "{0}" -q -compression;'.format('qt'))
```